# Knapsack without repitions: Maximum Amount of Gold

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

From Coursera's Algorithmic Toolbox course.

**Problem Introduction**

You are given a set of bars of gold and your goal is to take as much gold as possible into
your bag. There is just one copy of each bar and for each bar you can either take it or not
(hence you cannot take a fraction of a bar).

**Problem Description**

Task. Given  gold bars, find the maximum weight of gold that fits into a bag of capacity .
Input Format. The first line of the input contains the capacity  of a knapsack and the number  of bars of gold. The next line contains  integers 0,1, . . . ,−1 defining the weights of the bars of gold.

Constraints. 1 ≤  ≤ 10^4; 1 ≤  ≤ 300; 0 ≤ 0, . . . , −1 ≤ 10^5.

Output Format. Output the maximum weight of gold that fits into a knapsack of capacity .

My solution in C++:

```
const int WEIGHT_MAX = 1000 + 1;
const int ITEMS_COUNT_MAX = 300 + 1;

int optimal_weight(int W, const vector<int> &w) {
  int weights[ITEMS_COUNT_MAX][WEIGHT_MAX];
  const int w_size = w.size();

  for (int i = 0; i <= w_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= W; j++) {      
        if (i==0 || j==0) 
          weights[i][j] = 0;
        else if (w[i - 1] <= j) 
          weights[i][j] = std::max(w[i - 1] + weights[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]],  weights[i - 1][j]);
        else
          weights[i][j] = weights[i - 1][j];
    }
  }

  int result = weights[w_size][W];
  return result;
}
```

For the input

```
10 3
1 4 8
```

...it produces following 2D matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
0 1 1 1 4 5 5 5 8 9 9
```

But 9th of 14 graders's test is not passed. The grader doesn't provide input it used.

Can someone please point me out possible caveats in the solution?

**UPDATED [SOLVED thanks to Matt]:**
Memory must be allocated on the heap because the local stack size is not enough to hold the array of size 10001х301. Actually, getting segmentation fault error trying to allocate on the stack.

```
int optimal_weight(int W, const vector<int> &w) {
  const int w_size = w.size();
  int** weights = new int* [w_size + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i <= w_size; i++) {
    weights[i] = new int[W + 1];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= w_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= W; j++) {      
        if (i==0 || j==0) {
          weights[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else if (w[i - 1] <= j) 
          weights[i][j] = std::max(w[i - 1] + weights[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]],  weights[i - 1][j]);
        else
          weights[i][j] = weights[i - 1][j];
    }
  }

  int result = weights[w_size][W];

  for (int i = 0; i < w_size; i++) {
    delete[] weights[i];
  }

  delete[] weights;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Could it be a timing issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation is fine, but the max weight is 10000 and your matrix only goes up to 1001, so you're getting a buffer overrun.

It's not nice to allocate your matrix on the stack in the first place, and it'll be much worse when you fix that problem.

Also you don't really need a 2-dimensional matrix to solve this problem.

Try maintaining a sorted list of accessible weights.  Start with [0] and add the newly accessible weights for each item.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Yes, you're correct about restrictions! I've updated the question.

Comment: That algorithm gives me correct results all the time. I've even implemented a test generating random data and the result was always correct. I'm becoming to conclusion that the problem is with grader.

Comment: You missed the part about the buffer overrun?  Try it with W=10000

Comment: Yup, I totally messed up with local stack restrictions. Thank you again, Matt!

Comment: I didn't consider any other way of solving this other than with help of dynamic approach because it should be solved using knapsack 0/1 (no repitions) algorithm. Thank you for letting me know that there's one more way to accomplish this.